# Optimize non-linear function with two variables in Python

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am trying to optimize the following function:

```
f(x,a+,a-,b) = a+*((1/(1+exp(-b*x)) - 1/2) if x>=0
             = a-*((1/1+exp(-b*x)) -1/2)  if x<0 

constraints: a+ * b <=4, a-*b <=4
             a+/2 <= max(if(x>0))
             a-/2 <= -min(if(x<0))
```

I have tried to use the minimize function in scpiy with by putting the bounds [(0,2), (0,2), (1,None)] and constraints as defined above, but the function is not providing the right results, especially if I use beta to be an args in the constraints.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize 

init_params=[0.0,0.0,20.0]
bnds = [(0.0,2.0), (0.0,2.0), (1.0,None)]
S_curve = pd.DataFrame()
S_curve['year'] = dfs2.index
S_curve['H_Change'] = np.array(dfs2.loc[:,'annualH_chg'])
S_curve['R_Change'] = np.array(dfs2.loc[:,'annualR_chg'])
S_curve['Weight'] = 1
S_curve.reset_index(drop=True)
weighted = S_curve[S_curve.Weight !=0]
minimum = -S_curve['R_Change'].min()
maximum = S_curve['R_Change'].max()
beta=init_params[2]

def constraint1(up, beta):
    return 4.0-(up*beta)

def constraint2(down, beta):
    return 4.0-(down*beta)

def constraint3(up, maximum):
    return maximum - up/2.0

def constraint4(down, minimum):
    return minimum - down/2.0

cons = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun':constraint1, 'args':(beta,)},
        {'type':'ineq', 'fun':constraint2, 'args':(beta,)},
        {'type':'ineq', 'fun':constraint3, 'args':(maximum,)},
        {'type':'ineq', 'fun':constraint4, 'args':(minimum,)}]

soln = minimize(func, init_params, bounds=bnds, constraints=cons, method='SLQSP')
```

expecting the first and second constraint to be satisfied, and beta (b) is not constant.